# SpringBoot + PostgreSQL "Column does not exist"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to retrieve all data from the table but getting

> "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column tenantenti0_.module_name does not exist"

I have tried all the below still the issue persists:

1. Adding in application.properties file --> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${your-default-schema-name}
2. No camel case issue either in table column name or at code side.
3. Have mentioned the schema name as well under @Table(name = "tenant_info", schema = "public"), however for me it's public so shouldn't effect only in case of custom schema it needs to be mentioned.
4. Have tried using @namedQuery in entity class and @query in repository class still the same issue.

Below is my Entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_info", schema = "public")
@NamedQuery(name = "TenantEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TenantEntity t")
@ApplicationScope
public class TenantEntity implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenantId;

    @Column(name = "module_name")
    private String moduleName;
    
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Below is my Repository class:@Repository

```java
public interface TenantRepository extends JpaRepository<TenantEntity, String> {

    public List<TenantEntity> findAll();

    public TenantEntity findByTenantId(String tenantId);

    public List<TenantEntity> findByModuleName(String moduleName);
}
```

Have attached the table pic.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tenant_info ( 
    id integer NOT NULL, 
    tenant_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, 
    module_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, 
    url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, 
    username text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, 
    password text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT tenant_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

[image]

Comment: please set in the application.properties:
hibernate.show_sql=false and restart the app/test. You will see the generated SQL request and will be able to execute it in say Valentina Studio

Comment: @dimirsenZ shouldn't that be `hibernate.show_sql=true` ?

Comment: Have you connected to the database and verified the column actually exists? Why are you assuming the error message is incorrect?

Comment: Mark B
indeed. I copied it from my project as is

Comment: Please post the DDL of the table.

Comment: @JensSchauder below is the DDL of my table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tenant_info
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    tenant_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    module_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    username text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tenant_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

Comment: @MarkB i have connected to DB and have added an image as well, i am not allowed to post any images yet, hence the image has been converted in form of URL, at the very beginning of this post mentioned as "enter image description here".

Comment: @dimirsenZ i have added the hibernate.show_sql=true and below is the query getting generated:
Hibernate: 
    select
        tenantenti0_.id as id1_0_,
        tenantenti0_.module_name as module_n2_0_,
        tenantenti0_.password as password3_0_,
        tenantenti0_.tenant_id as tenant_i4_0_,
        tenantenti0_.url as url5_0_,
        tenantenti0_.username as username6_0_ 
    from
        public.tenant_info tenantenti0_

Comment: Tushar Kumar So now you can execute this SQL outside your app - in IDE or in whatever program like Valentina Studio. If you reproduce your error, then the root cuase is beyond your application

Answer (score 2):

I think that there could be two problems you are facing and I cannot comment  so I have to answer just to try to help(Sorry if not useful). I believe that it may not be the schema but I would need you to upload your sql for the table to see it. It seems that it may be column not the table but the problem may be with

```
@Column(name = "module_name")
private String moduleName;
```

If you look at your sql if you have quotes in postgres you may  have to escape them in your java code for it to work properly. Which would make it

```
@Column(name = "\"module_name\"")
private String moduleName;
```

Once again sorry if it isn't helpful But can't comment yet so really hopeful that this will help. When I had schema naming issue it wouldn't even say column doesn't exist but the table as a whole would be missing.

Comment: DId you try the escape characters on the table and schema name as well in java class?

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused because your database schema is not in synced with your Entity class. My advice is to inspect your database schema to see if your table has all the columns you expected. Might be more helpful if you show us your database table ;)

Comment: I have added the image "enter image description here" at the very beginning of this post, and have added the DDL query as well in reply to main post.